# 99% CPU usage for no reason

Tags: cpu, process, system-monitor

10 minutes ago I was just surfing the web as usual on my Ubuntu 10.04, when all of a sudden the system became slow. I realized that the CPU usage is 99%. I opened System monitor and everything seemed fine. I couldn't see any process that used a lot of CPU. I logged out and logged in, and CPU usage was still 99%. Then I rebooted and now everything is ok.

What happened and why couldn't I see the process that used so much CPU? What to do if that happens again? I want to solve the problem, not to reboot every time that happens.

---

Here it is again. It's because of Gparted. Everything worked fine until I started it. And now it's 99% again. I closed Gparted and still 99%. I can't find gparted process. Here is the "top" output

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                              
 1570 tuks      20   0 40720 3644 2832 S   29  0.1   2:04.88 gvfs-gdu-volume                      
 1572 root      20   0 15800 3156 2444 R   24  0.1   1:45.74 udisks-daemon                        
 2058 tuks      20   0  649m 257m  34m S   22  6.4 161:26.52 firefox                              
 1556 tuks      20   0 18676 7104 5504 R   16  0.2   1:08.85 gdu-notificatio                      
  906 messageb  20   0  9292 7448  760 R   16  0.2   1:09.08 dbus-daemon                          
 2066 tuks      20   0 41864  11m 8412 S   16  0.3   1:11.66 update-notifier                      
  500 root      18  -2  2624  944  332 S    6  0.0   0:26.09 udevd                                
 6250 tuks      20   0  360m 150m  21m S    5  3.7  45:30.14 plugin-containe                      
 1065 root      20   0 78444  36m  12m S    4  0.9 224:50.06 Xorg                                 
 1427 tuks       9 -11  158m  10m 8592 S    3  0.3  23:28.05 pulseaudio                           
  369 root      20   0  4104 1268  980 S    3  0.0   0:11.06 mountall                             
    1 root      20   0  2792 1720 1200 S    2  0.0   0:09.07 init                                 
  392 root      20   0  2312  824  612 S    2  0.0   0:06.68 upstart-udev-br                      
  394 root      16  -4  2644  964  308 S    1  0.0   0:05.96 udevd                                
 1419 tuks      20   0 57288  21m  11m S    1  0.5   8:21.97 python                               
 1411 tuks      20   0 83048  30m 9524 S    1  0.8  50:33.01 compiz                               
 1444 tuks      20   0 57152  21m  11m S    1  0.5   6:06.30 python                               
 6834 tuks      20   0 79980  27m  19m S    1  0.7   5:49.54 smplayer                             
 1438 tuks      20   0 58376  22m  11m S    1  0.6   4:30.69 python                               
 1440 tuks      20   0  239m  56m  19m S    1  1.4   7:45.33 skype                                
 5045 tuks      20   0 52204  13m 9.8m S    1  0.3   0:01.65 gnome-terminal
```

---

Now I logged out and logged in and CPU usage is normal. I started Gparted and this time everything is ok. I am very confused

Answer (score 1):

Well you could run `top` command in the terminal to know the process eating away your CPU and if you want to kill the process you just have to note down the PID of the process (left side of the terminal under PID). Once the process PID is known, you can kill the process by running `kill PID XXXX`

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I have already run the "top" command and still nothing

Comment: @tuks Please select all the text in the Terminal while `top` is running, copy it to the clipboard, **edit your question**, and paste it in. Make sure to use the <$> tool in the Ask Ubuntu editing toolbar so that it appears correctly. This should help to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I think it was the update manager process which caused such a situation. I witnessed this same thing on 12.04 last week. I wouldn't worry too much about it unless the issue persists